# "Device driver software was unsuccessfuly installed" message with DVD drive

Tags: windows-7, drivers, dvd

I have a Asus DRW-24B1LT DVD drive in Windows 7 64bit. The drive used to work fine for months and it stopped working suddenly and its driver letter is gone. In the device manager, there's a yellow exclamation mark beside the model name.  I did several tries to uninstall the driver and do a scan for hardware changes and I get a message "Device driver software was unsuccessfully installed". When I do an update driver, it says the driver is current. I tried a different Sata port, but it's the same problem.

Asus's site has only a firmware to download. No driver. The DVD drive was installed by me. It didn't come with the system.

How to I troubleshoot this and get the drive to work properly again? Is there a tool to completely remove the drivers and do a "cleanup"?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725782.aspx) to delete the driver package

> To uninstall a device

```
Open Device Manager.

Double-click the type of device that you want to uninstall.

Right-click the specific device you want, and then click Uninstall.
You can also double-click the device, and then on the Driver tab, click 
Uninstall.

In the Confirm Device Removal page, select Delete the driver software for
this device if you also want to remove the device driver package from the
driver store.

The Delete the driver software for this device option removes the package
from the driver store. It does not remove the currently installed driver
for any other operational devices that use the same driver. If you remove
the driver from the store, and the device is connected to the computer 
again, Windows must search for a copy of the driver package in the standard
search locations, including possibly prompting the user for media. 
This option is the equivalent of running the command:
pnputil -d -f <package.inf>. 
For more information, see Remove a Driver Package from the Driver Store.

Click OK to complete the uninstall process.

When the uninstall process is complete, unplug the device from the computer.

If you are prompted to restart the computer, the removal is not completed
and the device might continue to function until the computer is restarted.
```

Comment: There's no option to delete anything in the confirm dialog. I see it on for other drivers for other devices. I think it's because the driver is cdrom.sys which is a Windows driver and not a third party one.

Comment: If the drive appears in the BIOS, try using the drive to boot from your windows cd. If that works then it's definitely the driver.